# exclude svn files in Orchard deployment

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms, msdeploy

When I create a deployment package in VS2010 for an orchard integrated project, the svn files as well as the db_data are always included.

It's quite clumsy and **how can I exclude all those svn folder and files from VS2010 project config?**

I found something like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <!-- This will exclude the .xml files from the bin folder -->    
  <ExcludeFromPackageFiles Include="$(OutputPath)*.xml" />  

  <!-- This will exclude the tmp folder from the bin folder -->    
  <ExcludeFromPackageFolders  Include="$(OutputPath)tmp" />  
</ItemGroup>
```

but I don't understand where OutputPath applies to in my Orchard Project. Because there are heaps of svn files in other orchard solutions.

Comment: Please see this SO Post.



http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340984/visual-studio-2010-how-to-exclude-folder-files-from-build-deployment-package

Comment: No this doesn't really resolve my issue.  the Orchard solution has heaps of projects.  Will I edit each project to exclude svn files?  it seems a tedious work.