# Deployment exclude files or folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-deployment, publish

I try to publish my ASP.Net MVC project and i keep getting this error

> Error 30  Copying file bin\Castle.Core.xml to
>   obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Castle.Core.xml failed. Could not
>   find file 'bin\Castle.Core.xml'.      0   0   XXX.YYYY.UI

I understand this is because of missing Castle.Core.xml in the bin folder, so how could i configure to not letting the compiler to copy this file?

The Castle.core.xml file will be deleted each time i rebuild the project so i'm tired copy into bin again and again.

**Things i tried**
I tried [this](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/excluding-files-and-folders-from-deployment) approach from Microsoft but still no different. and this is the wpp.target file

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ExcludeFromPackageFolders Include="bin\*.xml">
      <FromTarget>ContactManager.Mvc.wpp.targets</FromTarget>
    </ExcludeFromPackageFolders>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

and also i tried to edit my .csproj file to exclude by adding these line which i read from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340984/visual-studio-2010-how-to-exclude-folder-files-from-build-deployment-package)

```
<ItemGroup>
  <!-- This will exclude the .xml files from the bin folder -->    
  <ExcludeFromPackageFiles Include="$(OutputPath)*.xml" />  

  <!-- This will exclude the tmp folder from the bin folder -->    
  <ExcludeFromPackageFolders  Include="$(OutputPath)tmp" />  
</ItemGroup>
```

Can anyone give advise on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Copy Local option in the Properties window available for this file? If so, change the Copy Local property to True.